# Finding All Occurrences of a Word in a Dictionary of Lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out which line numbers a certain word appears in. Say for example I have the following dictionary of lists. Here each list is a line in a paragraph.

```
{1: ['They', 'seek', 'him', 'here'], 
2: ['they', 'seek', 'him', 'there'], 
3: ['those', 'Frenchies', 'seek', 'him', 'everywhere']}
```

I want to find all the lines where the word "him" appears. It's pretty clear that it appears in lines 1,2,3 just by looking at it but how would I have my output tell me which lines it appears in?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do this once, you can use the below:

```
[k for (k, v) in d.items() if 'him' in v]
```

If you plan on doing this many times, I would suggest you build another dictionary mapping the word to the lines it appears in.

Answer (score 0):

```
z={1: ['They', 'seek', 'him', 'here'], 
2: ['they', 'seek', 'him', 'there'], 
3: ['those', 'Frenchies', 'seek', 'him', 'everywhere']}

indices=[k for k in z if 'him' in z[k]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys and check if the search phrase is present in each list. Please see if this code helps:

```
searchPhrase = "him"
lines = []
for i in iDict:
    if(searchPhrase in iDict[i])
        lines.append(i)
print(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple solution.

```
d={1: ['They', 'seek', 'him', 'here'], 2: ['they', 'seek', 'him', 'there'], 3: ['those', 'Frenchies', 'seek', 'him', 'everywhere']}
word="him"
lines=[]
for i in d:
    if word in d[i]:
        lines.append(i)
print lines
```